# Difference between programmers and cs.stackexchange

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I recently found cs.stackexchange and have been confused with the difference between programmers and cs.

[The about page of cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/about) isn't very detailed and only mentions `specific issues with computer science` alongwith `real problems` which, to my knowledge, is in every stackexchange site.

Isn't that already covered by this website?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference between the two sites is the difference between [computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science) and [software engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_engineering).

Programmers is focused on the practical aspects of building software - requirements, architecture, design, testing, deployment, configuration management, software quality, process and project management. Things of unique interest to software engineers are also on topic - software licenses, business aspects unique to software development.

Computer Science is more theoretical and mathematical in nature - programming language concepts, languages and grammars, complexity theory, computability.

There is, however, some overlap. For example, there may be a set of data structure or algorithm questions that can be asked to either community. However, the answers you get would vary. Here on Programmers, I would expect answers to be more concerned with a different set of trade-offs than on Computer Science - ease of implementation, maintenance, testability, the existence of well-used implementation versus time and/or space complexity.

Comment: During CS's early days, we've tested the overlap: [Why is quicksort better than other sorting algorithms in practice?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/150615/25936) (ProgSE), [Why is quicksort better than other sorting algorithms in practice?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3/773) (CS). The different approach in answering the same question is revealing.

Comment: @YannisRizos Thanks for those links. It helped me decide which I needed to use more.

Comment: @AseemBansal Rule of thumb: If you are learning, use CS. If you are building stuff, use Programmers. If you happen to pick the wrong site, no worries, we can always migrate the question.